# Composed query params for rspec api documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-api-documentation

I' working on the tests and documentation of a searches endpoint that I implemented. I'm having trouble with properly adding the query params. Basically the request url should look like this

```
"/api/v3/workspaces/1/searches?filter[query]=b&filter[type]=ct:Tag,User,WorkingArea"
```

My controller looks like this

```
class SearchesController < ApiV3Controller
    load_and_authorize_resource :workspace
    load_and_authorize_resource :user, through: :workspace
    load_and_authorize_resource :working_area, through: :workspace
    load_and_authorize_resource :tag, through: :workspace

    def index
      @resources = relevant_search_results

      render_json(@resources)
    end

    private

    def ability_klasses
      [WorkspaceAbility, UserWorkspaceAbility, WorkingAreaAbility, TagAbility]
    end

    def relevant_search_results
      query = filtered_params[:query]
      types = filtered_params[:type]
      items = params[:items]
      GlobalSearcher.new(query, types, items, @workspace).relevant_search_results
    end

    def render_json(resources)
      render json: resources, status: :ok
    end

    def filtered_params
      params.require(:filter).permit(:query, :type)
    end
  end
```

The functionality works as it should. The issue is with the the tests. Here's what the spec file looks like:

```
resource "Searches", :include_basic_variables, type: :api do

parameter :filter
parameter :type
parameter :items
let(:query) { "be" }
let(:type) { "ct:Tag,User,WorkingArea" }
let(:items) { "3" }
let_it_be(:workspace_id) { company.id }
explanation "Searches resource"
 route "/api/v3/workspaces/:workspace_id/searches", "Index" do
with_options with_example: true, required: true do
  parameter :workspace_id, "Workspace ID", type: :integer, example: 1
end


get "List all the relevant items" do
  context "Authenticated" do
    before { sign_in(admin) }

    example 'Search results' do
      do_request

      expect(query_string).to eq("filter[query]=b&filter[type]=ct:Tag,User,WorkingArea&items=3")
      expect(status).to eq 200
    end
  end
end
```

The error I get when running rspec is

```
expected: "filter[query]=b&filter[type]=ct:Tag,User,WorkingArea&items=3"
got: "query=be&type=ct%3ATag%2CUser%2CWorkingArea&items=3
```

Comment: Do you need to test the query string? The query string an implementation detail which may change. Instead, test that it has the desired effect.

Comment: What is `:include_basic_variables:`?

Comment: @Schwern I agree, I was using it to get an idea of what the request looks like and to give a clear error log here.

Comment: @Schwern We implemented :include_basic_variables to include all the objects created by factories that are reusable over and over in spec files.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller takes two parameters, filter and items. type is not a parameter.

You never give filter a value. filter is a hash parameter with the keys query and type, but you have not made that connection. My understanding is rspec-api-documentation will infer the type from the value.

```
parameter :filter
parameter :items
let(:filter) do
  { query: "be", type: "ct:Tag,User,WorkingArea" }
end
let(:items) { "3" }
```

Note that you should not be testing the query string directly, that's an implementation detail. You should be testing the query has the desired effect.